# How can I read an interactive program's results with exec()?

Tags: php, exec

For example, top runs until you exit, so `exec('top')` won't work, you need to use `exec('top -n 1')` which only displays one iteration of top.

I'm trying to get the results of vnstat, but it doesn't have an option like top does to only display one iteration.

Is there anything else I can do other than using a non-PHP script to generate the report, and then using PHP to read that?

Comment: Never experimented much in this field, but If i'm right, you'd have to use a pipe/stream type of scenario, ajax will be out of the question, as you will be constantly returning the first single results.. Then again, possibly AJAX, but check for changes from the previous JSON return and update your HTML accordingly